# Three tabs launching at once

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using ViewPager with TabLayout and fragments in my application. I want to make my app launch fragments activity when user is seeing it, but app is laoding 3 fragments at once. It means that if I have 3 tabs and user is actually on middle fragment both left and right fragments launched already onCreateView. Is there any way to make app do something when fragment is displayed on screen not when it's next to shown fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by adding this snippet to your fragments which are displayed in your viewpager :

```
private int mViewState = 0;
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        setViewState(mViewState & ~1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setViewState(mViewState | 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        setViewState(mViewState);
    }

    private void setViewState(int newState) {
        newState = getUserVisibleHint() ? newState | 2 : newState & ~2;
        if (newState == 3 && mViewState != 3){
        // I'm visible
        }else if (newState != 3 && mViewState == 3) {
        // I'm hidden
        }
        mViewState = newState;
    }
```